# RecyclerView fica atrás/escondido da ToolBar/ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

**Solução:** [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189316/27238)

Boa noite pessoal, como estão?
Estou com um problema e pra ficar mais claro tirei um print para mostra para vocês:

[image: Print do erro]

Como vocês podem ver a lista (RecyclerView) esta ficando por trás enquanto ela deveria ficar a baixo da Toolbar/Actionbar, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, mas não consegui resolver esse problema, alguém conhece a solução?
Só estou usando a biblioteca de suporte e mais nada, o erro ocorre tanto no emulador quanto no Android 4.1 e no 7 também, ambos dispositivos reais.
Esse toolbar se esconde quando o usuário desce a tela, no caso quando passa o dedo de baixo para cima, mas isso não é um problema eu realmente configurei para funcionar assim.

Já pesquisei de diversas maneiras mas não consegui nada relacionado a isso, sempre vem resultados de outros problemas ou de outras funcionalidades.

Caso eu ache a solução postarei aqui...

Segue XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListContatosActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srl_swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_list"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_cadastro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Opa, você está utilizando como view pai o Relative layout?

Se você estiver utilizando como view pai o RelativeLayout, você adciona a propriedade layout_below no SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/srl_swipe"
android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_list"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/> 
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Desculpa a falha amigo não sei pq não pegou o XML todo se dei ctrl+a, mas a view pai é um CoordinatorLayout, vou editar a pergunta e colocar o XML todo.

Comment: O problema foi aqui no Stackoverflow, as view pai tinha ficado fora das tags de código e não foram exibidas por isso...

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a resposta dele não foi muito grande, mas foi direto ao ponto e me levou a solução, ele não deu uma explicação teórica mas mesmo assim a resposta ajudou a solucionar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Diante da valiosa [ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189309/27238) do nosso colega [Natan Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/68067/natan-felipe) cheguei na seguinte solução, busquei um substituto para o `layout_below` no `CoordinatorLayout` que por ignorância minha já estava no meu XML porém no local errado através dessa [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37482482/5070907) cheguei a propriedade `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` que estava no meu `RecyclerView` retirei a propriedade dele e pronto coloquei ela no `SwipeRefreshLayout` e tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado a todos.